# Flex mobile app distriubtion Ad Hoc package can't install on tester's device

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, distribution

I have released a Ad hoc package for limited distribution. I added all tester's device to the provisioning profile. I intalled the Ad package on my device (Iphone 4, ios 4.3.3, jailbreak), it works.
 However, it can't install on other tester's device(ios 5). ipad show the error message on itunes ,"The app [app name] was not installed on the IPad, because it is not compatible on this IPad." IPhone show the error message on the phone "app is failed to install".

Is there any solution to fix this problem? I don't if the mobile app only works on jailbreak phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your your-app.xml if you have both for iPhone and iPad.

```
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
```

On another note, in Flash Builder, go to your projects properties >> Flex Build Packaging >> Apple iOS >> (you would need a native extension, even if you don't use it), and add the sdk folder of iOS 5.1. This way your App will be compiled to iOS 5.1.